# Do crawlers add page views on a forum?

Tags: forum, spam-bots

I have a MyBB forum and I get multiple page views on new threads within 3-5 minutes of posting. I manually submit new URLs through Google Webmaster Tools which should if anything account for 1 page view, but not multiple. I don't have active members at the moment. Research leads me to believe my 100+ members who never post or respond to Admin emails are actually registration bots. So are these page views on my new content from real people or from web crawlers?

Comment: They could be spammers laying in wait.

Comment: It could just be browsers. Chrome preloads resources in the background. Add some logging code into your viewing php script to see all the relevant information about the requests, namely the IP and the user agent. This should help you pinpoint the source of the problem. If you have bots register automatically, you have homework to do! Add some protection, such as captcha, immediately.

Answer (score 2):

> Do crawlers add page views on a forum?

Quite probably. Crawlers make HTTP requests like any real visitor. Unless your forum software specifically excludes bots from it's page view count then bot traffic is included. (However, even if the forum separates bot traffic in its stats, I wouldn't have thought it would do this is real time as there are extra steps necessary in order to determine whether it is a bot or not - and you want to avoid doing this as the page is served to the client.)

> which should if anything account for 1 page view, but not multiple.

When Google indexes a URL you could well get more than 1 visit from different crawlers (mobile, desktop, etc.).

Check your access logs / analytics / stats software. Check the IP addresses (reverse lookup), user-agents and HTTP referers. With just a handful of page views you should be able to determine whether these are bots or real visitors.

As @Zdenek suggested in comments, the multiple page views could simply be down to the browsers pre-fetch mechanism when you are viewing related pages eg. `<link rel="prefetch" href="...">`. Linked pages can be downloaded in the background (triggering a page view) in order to speed up the user's browsing experience.

Comment: With Google, there is only one crawler. How it presents itself (user agent) and what is done with the fetch in the way of post processing is dependent upon the entity that submitted the request for a fetch in the queue. There is a lot of overlap with no need to actually create multiple crawlers. It just appears as though there are. If a the regular googlebot fetches a page, you can assume that mobile is included and vice versa. Obviously, there are various reasons to fetch a page more than once periodically. Though that is not the norm.